# Fixed Memory location in C

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

Assign a memory location with address `0x67AB` and value `0x1234` using pointers.
i am trying to assign a fixed location in memory using pointers and not using `malloc()`

Comment: In general, code like this is likely to crash.  Do you have extra info, not included in the question, that guarantees this address is writeable by your code?

Comment: Do you have the guarantee that it is possible to write to the address 0x67AB?

Comment: @simonc  Programming in a micro-crontoller is filled with such activity that does not crash.

Comment: @chux Agreed.  The question doesn't mention that the code is targeting a micro-controller though.  Given that most questions at this level come from people who're just starting to learn C, it seems possible that the OP is hoping to run this code on a desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code writes `0x1234` to the address `0x67AB` in the address space of the executing process, provided your C implementation supports this behavior (as it goes beyond what the C standard requires). You may need to use a type other than `uint16_t`, depending on your precise needs. If you do not know what you are doing, this code will likely fail or cause other problems:

```
#include <stdint.h>
…
* (uint16_t *) 0x67AB = 0x1234;
```

Comment: +1 I like the succinctness of `*(uint16_t *) 0x67AB = 0x1234;`.

Answer (score 1):

If your program is running under an operating system, you will not be able to write to a fix location. In order to do something like this your program would need to have root access and make a system call so that the operative system itself writes on that location.

However, if you're writing a program for a micro-controller or an embedded system this is how you do it:

```
char* p = (char*)0x67AB;
p[0] = 0x12; // You need to write each byte at a time.
p[1] = 0x34;
```

Comment: Running under an operating system, with a virtual address space, prevents you from writing to an arbitrary physical memory address. It does not prevent you from writing to a fixed virtual memory address, if that address is mapped. There are, very rarely, occasions for doing so, if the loader or program sections linked into the process provide guarantees that certain addresses are used for certain things.

Comment: Whether a byte at a time must be written, and whether this is the correct order in which to write them, is implementation dependent. Also `67ABh` is not standard C syntax. It should be `0x67AB`, and it should be cast to a `char *`.

Comment: I think you're right. It has been a long time since I've written pure C so I didn't remember that well. I think I fixed it now, though.

Comment: The fix you did does not deal with the endian issue.  In a little endian architecture, it should be `p[0] = 0x34; p[1] = 0x12;`.  Further, writing one byte at a time is _not_ required.  One could use `* (uint16_t *) 0x67AB = 0x1234;` and write the 2 bytes simultaneously on a 16+ bit embedded system.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know writing to a specific address if OK, as in a PIC or controller:

```
#include <stdint.h>
int16_t *ptr = (int16_t *) 0x67AB;
*ptr = 0x1234;
```

As the endian of integer is not specified, a byte-by-byte setting may not provided expected behavior.